# Why does emacs insert a `#coding` header into my file?

Tags: character-encoding

I have a file where every time I save the file emacs inserts a `# coding: utf-8` at the top of the file. I'm using the `prelude` package.

How do I turn this off? I'm having a hard time tracing where this is coming from.

Comment: This has been answered elsewhere:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291017/how-can-i-avoid-putting-the-magic-encoding-comment-on-top-of-every-utf-8-file-in/6043834#6043834

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't an Emacs thing, it's a Unicode POSIX thing that Emacs has support for and many other editors and IDEs do not (or just ignore it).  The intention is to provide a means of telling an OS which files are UTF-8 and which are some other regional default or standard encoding.  Which, in turn, avoids encoding conflicts between character sets (where something other than UTF-8 is used).